# What are your biggest productivity vampires as a developer?

Tags: interviewing, productivity, meetings

Curious to hear from my fellow developers as to what the biggest drains on your time are that take you away from doing productive work.

Comment: This is not how tags were meant to be used though. There is an "Answer Your Question" button at the bottom for this purpose.

Comment: for me the answer is "Splatoon 2"

Answer (score 2):

1. **Meetings where I have no say/don't want it.** I have spent a fair bit of time in meetings where I have no involvement in the subject matter whatsoever, I just get lumped in because I am part of a group that does have someone who needs to be informed, so they just invite the group. For example, I was in a meeting on government grants a few weeks ago. I am not involved in grant writing, idea generation for grant ideas, or budgets at all. Yet my entire department was there as the business people all belonged in that meeting.
2. **Corporate culture stuff.** This is rarer than meetings which are not related to what I do, but a ton of time is spent expressing values, talking about values, and all sorts of talking about "who we are" as an organization. I have encountered this everywhere and I surf LinkedIn jobs throughout.
3. **Bad specs** Fairly self explanatory. A lot of time is spent on work which is incorrectly specified, causing it to need to be redone.
4. **Paperwork.** I am spending an increasing amount of time writing things nobody will ever read and updating goals created for the purpose of being updated in our goal tracking software.
5. **Technology clashes**. People at my company use Windows, Mac, and Linux. A lot of time is spent dealing with minor errors and differences in development between them. For example `0.0.0.0` is valid on Mac and Linux, but not Windows. Same with a lot of the automated node commands and file paths.

Comment: Add **phone calls** or **personal visits at your desk** from others for every fart, that rip you out of everything you do, although they could use email too.